# Calculating the Recurrence Relation T(n)=T(n-1)+logn

Tags: recursion, big-o, complexity-theory, recurrence

We are to solve the recurrence relation through repeating substitution:

```
T(n)=T(n-1)+logn
```

I started the substitution and got the following.

```
T(n)=T(n-2)+log(n)+log(n-1)
```

By logarithm product rule, log(mn)=logm+logn,

```
T(n)=T(n-2)+log[n*(n-1)]
```

Continuing this, I get

```
T(n)=T(n-k)+log[n*(n-1)*...*(n-k)]
```

We know that the base case is T(1), so n-1=k -> k=n+1, and substituting this in we get

```
T(n)=T(1)+log[n*(n-1)*...*1]
```

Clearly n*(n-1)*...*1 = n! so,

```
T(n)=T(1)+log(n!)
```

I do not know how to solve beyond this point. Is the answer simply **O(log(n!))**? I have read other explanations saying that it is Θ(nlogn) and thus it follows that O(nlogn) and Ω(nlogn) are the upper and lower bounds respectively.

Comment: Θ(log(n!)) = Θ (n log n)

Comment: The `k` in that last two equations is just shouting... hey, what the hell I'm doing here if the rest of terms are independent of me?? That doesn't look right...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath k is the maximum # of steps for this recursion.

Comment: @Jay: rephrased. you mean k=n? ;)

Comment: @KarolyHorvath The way my professor (and some other explanations online) were doing it is to use k to represent a generic "maximum" substitution.

Comment: @Jay: the rest of the equations are fine. the last two: incorrect. I doubt your professor wrote anything like that. that should be T(0), T(1), ... something like that.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Oh yes, if you are referring to that, that was a typo. I will correct that now. My apologies.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This expands out to log (n!). You can see this because

> T(n) = T(n - 1) + log n
>
> = T(n - 2) + log (n - 1) + log n
>
> = T(n - 3) + log (n - 2) + log (n - 1) + log n
>
> = ...
>
> = T(0) + log 1 + log 2 + ... + log (n - 1) + log n
>
> = T(0) + log n!

The exact answer depends on what T(0) is, but this is Θ(log n!) for any fixed constant value of T(0).

A note - using [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), Θ(log n!) = Θ(n log n). That might help you relate this back to existing complexity classes.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 6):

Stirling's formula is not needed to get the big-Theta bound. It's O(n log n) because it's a sum of at most n terms each at most log n. It's Omega(n log n) because it's a sum of at least n/2 terms each at least log (n/2) = log n - 1.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a linear recurrence of the first order. It can be solved exactly. If your initial value is $T(1) = 0$, you do get $T(n) = \log n!$. You can approximate $\log n!$ (see [Stirling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_formula)):
$$
\ln n! = n \ln n - n + \frac{1}{2} \ln \pí n + O(\ln n)
$$

[Need LaTeX here!!]

Answer (score 0):

```
After log(n!) We all know;
    n!=n(n-1)(n-2)....
    n!=n.n.n.n.... 
(because if we consider only highest term then it's n so...)
    n!=n^n

Now put it to our question so,
    T(n)=1+log(n!)
    T(n)=1+log(n^n)
    T(n)=1+n(log(n))   
(According log property)
```