# Solving Recurrence Relation via Recursion Trees of the Form "T(n-1)"

Tags: algorithm, recursion, complexity-theory, computer-science

I understand that the Master Theorem and recursion tree can be used for "divide-and-conquer" recurrence relations (i.e. **T(n)=T(n/2)+1**).

However, how would I apply those concepts to T(n)=T(n-1)+logn?

To my understanding, you cannot apply the two concepts to (n-1) decrements. But the assignment and professor are requiring T(n)=T(n-1)+logn to be solved using recursion trees and master theorem.

Furthermore, is there any reason that the following is not the recursive expansion for the above function?

```
T(n)=T(n-3)+log(n-2)+log(n-1)+log(n)
```

According to my professor, it should not be log(n-2) and log(n-1) but rather

```
T(n)=T(n-3)+logn+logn+logn
```

which makes absolutely no sense to me.

Comment: The recursion tree is just a chain of length *n*. So *T(n) = T(0) + sum(i=1 to n, log(i)) = T(0) + log(n!) = Theta(T(0) + n log n)*

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/22618778/2336725 by the same person.  Why are you asking your question again?

Comment: @Teepeemm Because I understood the question yesterday, but I spoke with the professor today and he said 1) That I did it wrong and 2) That I am to do it using a recursion tree and master theorem, not recursive substitution as in the link you posted.

Comment: @Jay I think there is some kind of misunderstanding, because given your recurrence, `T(n)=T(n-3)+logn+logn+logn` is clearly false. Maybe your professor is hinting at the fact that `log(n-2) + log(n-1) + log(n) = Theta(3*log n)`

Comment: I'm assuming the last line should be `T(n)<=T(n-3)+log n+log n+log n`, which would eventually show `T(n)=O(n log n)`.  But I agree that there is a misunderstanding somewhere, since the top answer from yesterday is simpler, and gives a Theta bound instead of big O.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things,

1. The recursive definition states that you must replace `n` with `n-1` when calling `T(n)` again, so your logic is sound for `T(n)=T(n-3)+log(n-2)+log(n-1)+log(n)`.
2. Your can easily make the argument that `log(1) + log(2) + log(3) + ... log(n) = log(n!) = Theta(nlogn)`, and `log(n) + log(n) + log(n) ... + log(n) = nlog(n) = Theta(nlog(n))`

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Rate_of_growth_and_approximations_for_large_n

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

To look at it as a tree, it's actually just a tree with worst case height, i.e.

[image]

This is because at each call, There is only *one* subproblem to solve.

Answer (score 2):

The following is a subtractive version of the master theorem:

If T(n) = aT(n-c) + g(n) where c>=1 and g(n)=Theta(n^k) for k>=0, then

- T(n)=Theta(n^k) if a<1
- T(n)=Theta(n^{k+1}) if a=1
- T(n)=Theta(a^{n/c}) if a>1

It does not include the particular case you ask, but states a general result on decrements.